# Deleting multiple rows at once by range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

"Delete method of range class failed" error is coming in `emptyRows.EntireRow.Delete` line. I am trying to do this because I want to delete multiple rows at once because if I use a For loop to go over each cell and delete one by one, then in continuous conditional Rows(first attr cell blank in my case), one conditioned Row is left because row number changes after I delete the previous row. So I want to delete all rows at once so the row number changes AFTER deleting all rows. any solution?

BTW here the `trimData` function is used especially to trim only specific spaces so not using `Trim(cell)`, so ignore that.

```
Sub deleteBlankRows()
    Call declareVars
    Dim lastCellFromBottom As Range
    Dim lRange As Range
    Dim emptyCells As Range
    Set lastCellFromBottom = Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, g_attrStartCell.Column).End(xlUp)
    'MsgBox lastCellFromBottom
    'MsgBox g_firstDataRangeCell.Address
    Set lRange = Range(lastCellFromBottom, g_firstDataRangeCell)


    For i = 1 To lRange.Count
        For Each Cell In lRange
            Call trimData(Cell)
            If Cell.Value = "" Then
                If i = 1 Then
                    Set emptyCells = Cell
                Else
                    Set emptyCells = Union(emptyCells, Cell)
                End If
            End If
        Next Cell
    Next i
    emptyCells.EntireRow.Delete
    Set g_dataLastCellOfStartAttr = g_attrStartCell.End(xlDown)
    g_dataLastRowNum = g_dataLastCellOfStartAttr.Row
    g_dataRange.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of using For Each Cell, use a For Variable = X to Y with a Range.Cell(Variable, Column) method and focus on each cell. Once you've found a row you need to delete, delete it and use Variable = Variable - 1. Is it clear or should i write down a code?

Comment: I understood the logic but I am not able to write a proper code, can you write one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a For-Next i've used a Do-Loop. Still the principle is the same. Let's start with the example to show you how it works:

```
Sub SubExample()

    '------------------------------------'
    'CODE ACCESSORY TO THE EXAMPLE: BEGIN'
    'vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv'

    'Declarations
    Dim WksWorksheet01 As Worksheet
    Dim RngStart As Range
    Dim RngEnd As Range
    Dim LngCounter01 As Long
    Dim LngEndRow As Long
    Dim LngColumn As Long

    'Setting variables.
    Set WksWorksheet01 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    Set RngStart = WksWorksheet01.Range("A2")
    Set RngEnd = WksWorksheet01.Range("A10")

    'Typing header.
    RngStart.Offset(-1, 0).Value = "List"

    'Filling in a list.
    For LngCounter01 = 0 To (RngEnd.Row - RngStart.Row)
        RngStart.Offset(LngCounter01, 0) = LngCounter01
    Next

    'Creating a random blank cell in the list.
    RngStart.Offset(Round(Rnd() * (RngEnd.Row - RngStart.Row), 0), 0).ClearContents

    '^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^'
    'CODE ACCESSORY TO THE EXAMPLE: END'
    '----------------------------------'

    '---------------------------------'
    'CODE YOU ARE INTERESTED IN: BEGIN'
    'vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv'

    'Setting variables.
    LngCounter01 = RngStart.Row
    LngColumn = RngStart.column
    LngEndRow = RngEnd.Row

    'Loop the code until the range we are processing is below the end of the list.
    Do Until LngCounter01 > LngEndRow
        'Selecting the cell we are processing (just to help you following the code, not necessary to the code).
        WksWorksheet01.Cells(LngCounter01, LngColumn).Select
        'Checking if the cell is empty.
        If WksWorksheet01.Cells(LngCounter01, LngColumn).Value = "" Then
            'Deleting the cell. I'll also inform you about it (not necessary to the code).
            MsgBox "This cell is blank. I'll delete the row", vbOKOnly
            'Deleting.
            WksWorksheet01.Cells(LngCounter01, LngColumn).EntireRow.Delete
            'We've deleted a row, so the end had also got closer. Setting LngEndRow accordingly.
            LngEndRow = LngEndRow - 1
        Else
            'Ignoring the cell and proceed to the next. I'll also inform you about it (not necessary to the code).
            MsgBox "This cell is not blank. Proceeding to the next one.", vbOKOnly
            'Setting LngCounter01 for the next row.
            LngCounter01 = LngCounter01 + 1
        End If
    Loop

    '^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^'
    'CODE YOU ARE INTERESTED IN: END'
    ''------------------------------'

End Sub
```

You can copy-paste and run it. It will create a new sheet and show you how it works. Check the notes too. Based on this example i've tried to edit your code. Here it is with the changes highlighted:

```
Sub deleteBlankRowsCHANGESHIGHLIGHTED()
    Call declareVars
    Dim lastCellFromBottom As Range

    '--------CUT--------
    'v v v v v v v v v v
    'Dim lRange As Range
    '^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^

    Dim emptyCells As Range

    '---------ADDED---------
    'v v v v v v v v v v v v
    Dim LngCounter01 As Long
    Dim WksWorksheet01 As Worksheet
    '^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^

    Set lastCellFromBottom = Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, g_attrStartCell.column).End(xlUp)
    'MsgBox lastCellFromBottom
    'MsgBox g_firstDataRangeCell.Address

    '----------------------------CUT----------------------------
    'v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v
    'Set lRange = Range(lastCellFromBottom, g_firstdatarangecell)
    '^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^

    '----------------------------------ADDED----------------------------------
    'v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v
    'Setting variables.
    LngCounter01 = RngStart.Row
    LngColumn = RngStart.column
    LngEndRow = RngEnd.Row
    Set WksWorksheet01 = g_attrStartCell.Parent

    'Loop the code until the range we are processing is below the end of the list.
    Do Until LngCounter01 > LngEndRow
        'Selecting the cell we are processing (just to help you following the code, not necessary to the code).
        WksWorksheet01.Cells(LngCounter01, LngColumn).Select

        Call trimData(cell) '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< I'VE INSERTED YOUR COMMAND HERE


        'Checking if the cell is empty.
        If WksWorksheet01.Cells(LngCounter01, LngColumn).Value = "" Then
            'Deleting the cell. I'll also inform you about it (not necessary to the code).
            MsgBox "This cell is blank. I'll delete the row", vbOKOnly
            'Deleting.
            WksWorksheet01.Cells(LngCounter01, LngColumn).EntireRow.Delete
            'We've deleted a row, so the end had also got closer. Setting LngEndRow accordingly.
            LngEndRow = LngEndRow - 1
        Else
            'Ignoring the cell and proceed to the next. I'll also inform you about it (not necessary to the code).
            MsgBox "This cell is not blank. Proceeding to the next one.", vbOKOnly
            'Setting LngCounter01 for the next row.
            LngCounter01 = LngCounter01 + 1
        End If
    Loop
    '^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^

    '-----------------CUT-----------------
    'v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v
    'For i = 1 To lRange.Count
    '    For Each cell In lRange
    '        Call trimData(cell)
    '        If cell.Value = "" Then
    '            If i = 1 Then
    '                Set emptyCells = cell
    '            Else
    '                Set emptyCells = Union(emptyCells, cell)
    '            End If
    '        End If
    '    Next cell
    'Next i
    'emptyCells.EntireRow.Delete
    '^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^

    Set g_dataLastCellOfStartAttr = g_attrStartCell.End(xlDown)
    g_dataLastRowNum = g_dataLastCellOfStartAttr.Row
    g_dataRange.Select

End Sub
```

Here is the same code without the hightlights:

```
Sub deleteBlankRowsREFORMED()
    Call declareVars
    Dim lastCellFromBottom As Range
    Dim emptyCells As Range

    Dim LngCounter01 As Long
    Dim WksWorksheet01 As Worksheet

    Set lastCellFromBottom = Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, g_attrStartCell.column).End(xlUp)
    'MsgBox lastCellFromBottom
    'MsgBox g_firstDataRangeCell.Address

    'Setting variables.
    LngCounter01 = RngStart.Row
    LngColumn = RngStart.column
    LngEndRow = RngEnd.Row
    Set WksWorksheet01 = g_attrStartCell.Parent

    'Loop the code until the range we are processing is below the end of the list.
    Do Until LngCounter01 > LngEndRow
        'Selecting the cell we are processing (just to help you following the code, not necessary to the code).
        WksWorksheet01.Cells(LngCounter01, LngColumn).Select

        Call trimData(cell) '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< I'VE INSERTED YOUR COMMAND HERE


        'Checking if the cell is empty.
        If WksWorksheet01.Cells(LngCounter01, LngColumn).Value = "" Then
            'Deleting the cell. I'll also inform you about it (not necessary to the code).
            MsgBox "This cell is blank. I'll delete the row", vbOKOnly
            'Deleting.
            WksWorksheet01.Cells(LngCounter01, LngColumn).EntireRow.Delete
            'We've deleted a row, so the end had also got closer. Setting LngEndRow accordingly.
            LngEndRow = LngEndRow - 1
        Else
            'Ignoring the cell and proceed to the next. I'll also inform you about it (not necessary to the code).
            MsgBox "This cell is not blank. Proceeding to the next one.", vbOKOnly
            'Setting LngCounter01 for the next row.
            LngCounter01 = LngCounter01 + 1
        End If
    Loop

    Set g_dataLastCellOfStartAttr = g_attrStartCell.End(xlDown)
    g_dataLastRowNum = g_dataLastCellOfStartAttr.Row
    g_dataRange.Select

End Sub
```

Hope it's clear enouth. Tell me if it satisfies you, if you need any explanation or improvement.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly, and your logic and comments made me understand everything.